# CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-drawer

I have a layouting problem when combining `CoordinatorLayout` with an `AppBarLayout` and a `NavigationDrawer`.

The problem is, that the NavigationDrawer and it's content are hidden behind the toolbar. I have already did a lot of research and tried a lot of restructuring, but none of the "solutions" fixed my issue.

A demonstration can be found in this little Webm video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5zfc2x2ts2fws7/navigation_drawer_stackoverflow32523188.webm?dl=0

The base style is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

My **activity_overview.xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_long" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nvView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigationdrawer_main" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/overview_floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/overview_coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/fab_onscroll_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your CoordinatorLayout is wrapping your DrawerLayout and NavigationView, which means the Coordinator is in control of how everything is laid out. You need to nest the Coordinator inside the drawer, like so:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/overview_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_long" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/overview_floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/overview_coordinator_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/fab_onscroll_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigationdrawer_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

That should sort it out!

Comment: @slott How are you showing one? I haven't messed around with them, but this link seems to indicate that you'd need to attach an id to the co-ordinator and then pass that in as the view when you make the snackbar: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View, int, int)

Comment: @GeordieMatt why you added `android:clickable="true"` to `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I just reordered the original xml, so you'll have to ask the original poster :)

Answer (score 15):

To add on to the previous answer, you can make the DrawerLayout cleaner by moving the CoordinatorLayout+child elements into a separate xml file. And then just use the "include" option to add the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

  <!-- Widget Coordinator + child elements go here -->
  <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Good shout. Most of the time, I use the drawer as the layout for an activity, and then just load a fragment into FrameLayout where you've got your include. Means I can use the activity to handle all of my drawer-based navigation.

Comment: That is how Google's samples are designed as well. It is easily readable and maintainable if laid out this way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**Navigation drawer Documentation**](https://m2.material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android#modal-navigation-drawer), you can use the navigation drawer with a top app bar, like this code:

In the layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
...
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.PrimarySurface"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="@string/top_app_bar"app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="0dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Screen content -->
    <!-- Use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to fit below top app bar -->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In res/values/themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.*">
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

In res/layout/header_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

...
```

In code:

```
topAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
    drawerLayout.open()
}

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
    // Handle menu item selected
    menuItem.isChecked = true
    drawerLayout.close()
    true
}
```