# How to add views under collapsing toolbar layout?

Tags: java, android, view, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to add collapsing toolbar in my app. I want to add a graph layout also image view and text views inside the collapsing toolbar layout. Like this image.[image]

This graph is in collapsing toolbar layout. When we do scroll up graph goes up and remains as a toolbar.

Now I am trying to add views under collapsing toolbar layout. But I am not able to move them and align them. How to do?

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/appbar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_reorder_black_48dp"
            android:id="@+id/navigationMenu" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_check_box_white_24dp"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />

        <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />


        <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />



    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    style="@style/FabStyle"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_anchor = "@id/parentPanel"
    app:layout_anchorGravity  = "bottom|right|end"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="219dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
        fab:menu_fab_label="Menu label"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="addList" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="list1" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="list2" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="list3" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;

private FloatingActionButton fab1;
private FloatingActionButton fab2;
private FloatingActionButton fab3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final FloatingActionMenu menu1 = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu1);
    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("List Title");

    ImageView navigationMenu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.navigationMenu);

    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab3);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    fab3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);


    navigationMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,NavigationMenuActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left, R.anim.enter);

        }
    });

    menu1.setOnMenuButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (menu1.isOpened()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menu1.getMenuButtonLabelText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            menu1.toggle(true);
        }
    });
    menu1.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);


    dynamicToolbarColor();

    toolbarTextAppernce();
}


private void dynamicToolbarColor() {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.b);
    Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
            collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)));
        }
    });
}


private void toolbarTextAppernce() {
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapsedappbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expandedappbar);
}


private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = "";

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab1:
                text = fab1.getLabelText();
                break;
            case R.id.fab2:
                text = fab2.getLabelText();
                fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.fab3:
                text = fab3.getLabelText();
                fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

        }
    }
    };
}
```

Now I have a single image view inside collapsing toolbar layout and that I can't move or align. How to align view and add views under collapsing toolbar?

Thank you..

Comment: would you please post you java code...

Comment: Check this post you may find some hints. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523188/coordinatorlayout-appbarlayout-navigationdrawer/32523537#32523537

Answer (score 3):

`CollapsingToolbarLayout` is a subclass of `FrameLayout`.

For maximum flexibility, put all your widgets inside a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and make it the only child of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.  Also for best results with vertical sizing, set the height to a specific dimension.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/graph_toolbar_height"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <!-- graph UI here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: >public class CollapsingToolbarLayout extends FrameLayout

Comment: Oh, right. Confused with `AppBarLayout`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout inside collapsingtoolbarlayout and add your views in there.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="64dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_about"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="@string/about_title"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```